# How can I achieve a surround sound effect for android in PhoneGap?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-cli

How can i achieve a surround sound effect for android in phonegap? Like there is this OpenAL4Android. How do I use it in PhoneGap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a bit more research and found about the Web Audio API, because earlier I wasn't searching for JavaScript specifically...I should sue myself. And there's this [Channel Splitter Node](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChannelSplitterNode) and that's what I specifically wanted.